# Error #98123: WEBPACK not bundling CSS after running 'gatsby develop' command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

## Gatsby not working due to `Error #98123`.

Everything worked fine, but after installing tailwind and PostCSS NPM packages the error immerged. I've tried deleting the node_modules file but the error still persist.

### Project directory:

Top level files and directory.

```
.
├── node_modules
├── src
├── .gitignore
├── .prettierrc
├── gatsby-browser.js
├── gatsby-config.js
├── gatsby-node.js
├── gatsby-ssr.js
├── LICENSE
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── README.md
```

### NPM files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-blog",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A starter for a blog powered by Gatsby and Markdown",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.28",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
    "gatsby": "^2.23.12",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-emotion": "^4.3.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^2.5.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.3.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.13",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^2.3.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-typography": "^2.5.6",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.3.7",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.3.14",
    "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^3.5.6",
    "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "^2.4.7",
    "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "^2.3.6",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.14",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.8.20",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.7",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.20.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-typography": "^0.16.19",
    "tailwind.macro": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
    "typeface-merriweather": "0.0.72",
    "typeface-montserrat": "0.0.75",
    "typography": "^0.16.19",
    "typography-theme-wordpress-2016": "^0.16.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "0BSD",
  "main": "n/a",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

……………………………………………..

### Steps to reproduce.

- Clone [this](https://github.com/Romeo-Peter/romeopeter) repo
- Run `npm install`
- Run `Gatsby develop`

### Result Expected:

Server should run on `localhost:8000`

### Actual result:

This is error I get on the terminal after running the `gatsby develop` command.

```
ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Unexpected identifier

File: node_modules\typeface-montserrat\index.css


ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Unexpected identifier

File: node_modules\typeface-merriweather\index.css


ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @Romeo

Comment: Yeah, I did, but I can't remember exactly what I did to solve it. It's been a while @FabricioG